# Kotest - Not able to resolve kotest import statements - Unresolved reference: shouldBe

Tags: intellij-idea, kotest

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import io.kotest.matchers.shouldBe

class Test {

    @Test
    fun test() {
        val str = "abc"
        str shouldBe "abc"
    }
}
```

I am able to run the test from Intellj, However, IDE is not resolving shouldBe import. Seeing Unresolved reference: shouldBe message. IDE is not resolving any matchers from kotest.

I have invalid
Any pointers?

Comment: It seems like your IDE had an issue while indexing or resolving import statements. It happens often. You may try `close/open` the project/IDE or `invalidate caches`.

Comment: I tried all of these. Even I went ahead uninstall and installing IDEA. Event cleared the bazel cache. None of them fixed the issue

Comment: I also see kotest assertion lib added to external library in IDEA. However, not seeing shouldBe method present inside io.kotest.matchers

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure the dependencies are correctly added
2. Try to rebuild the project
3. Try to Invalidate Caches in IDEA: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/invalidate-caches.html
4. Try to reproduce the issue in the latest IDEA version.

If the issue persist:

Please create a ticket to KTIJ project and attach the project with the issue reproduction: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue

Thank you!